# Finding analytical solution for Matrix inverse with an unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I need an analytical solution for finding inverse of a matrix in terms of an unknown.

I will use following example to pose my question

**EXAMPLE:**

1. $\mathbf{H}$  is a $49\times 49$ matrix.
2. $rank(\mathbf{H})$ is 49. (full rank matrix)
3. $i^{th}$ column of $\mathbf{H}$ is denoted as $\mathbf{h}_i$
4. $\mathbf{M}$ is a matrix defined as

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{H}^{}\mathbf{H}^{T}&\mathbf{h}_{25}^{}+p\mathbf{h}_{32}^{}\\\mathbf{h}_{25}^{T}+p\mathbf{h}_{32}^{T}&1+p^2\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I need to compute $\mathbf{M}^{-1}$ in terms of unknown $p$. Can we have a closed form expression for this? Is it possible to keep $\mathbf{H}^{}\mathbf{H}^{T}$ intact solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your matrix $\ \mathbf{M}\ $ is singular.

More generally, if
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{A}&\mathbf{b}\\\mathbf{b}^{T}&c\end{bmatrix}\ ,
\end{equation}
where $\ \mathbf{A}\ $ is a non-singular symmetric square matrix, $\ \mathbf{b}\ $ a column vector with the same number of rows as $\ \mathbf{A}\ $, and $\ c\ $ is a scalar, and
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{D}&\mathbf{e}\\\mathbf{e}^{T}&f\end{bmatrix}\ ,
\end{equation}
then it follows from the equation
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{I}&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}^T&1 \end{bmatrix}&=&
\mathbf{M}\mathbf{M}^{-1}\\
&=&\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{A}&\mathbf{b}\\\mathbf{b}^{T}&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{D}&\mathbf{e}\\\mathbf{e}^{T}&f\end{bmatrix}\\
&=&
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{D}+\mathbf{b}\mathbf{e}^T&\mathbf{A}\mathbf{e}+f\,\mathbf{b}\\
\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{D}+c\,\mathbf{e}^T& \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{e}+c\,f
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
that $\ \mathbf{e} = -f\,\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}\ $ and $\ f \left(c-\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}\right)=1\ $. Thus, the inverse $\ \mathbf{M}^{-1}\ $ can exist only if $\ c-\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}\ne 0\ $.
If this condition *is* satisfied, then we get
\begin{eqnarray}
f &=& \left(c-\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}\right)^{-1}\ ,\\
\mathbf{e} &=& -f\,\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}\ ,\mbox{ and}\\
\mathbf{D} &=& \mathbf{A}^{-1}-f\,\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\ .
\end{eqnarray}
and with these values, it is easy to check that $\ \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{D}&\mathbf{e}\\\mathbf{e}^{T}&f\end{bmatrix}\ $ is indeed the inverse of $\ \mathbf{M}\ $.

In your case, $\ \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{H}\mathbf{H}^T\ $, $\ \mathbf{b}=\mathbf{h}_{25}+p\,\mathbf{h}_{32}\ $, and $\ c=1+p^2\ $, so the condition required for the inverse to exist becomes 
\begin{equation}
1+p^2-\left(\,\mathbf{h}_{25}+p\,\mathbf{h}_{32}\right)^{T}\left(\mathbf{H}^{T}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{H}^{-1}\left(\,\mathbf{h}_{25}+p\,\mathbf{h}_{32}\right)\ne 0\ .
\end{equation}
But $\ \mathbf{H}^{-1}\left(\,\mathbf{h}_{25}+p\,\mathbf{h}_{32}\right)= \mathbf{i}_{25}+p\,\mathbf{i}_{32}\ $, where $\ \mathbf{i}_i\ $ is the $\ i^\mathrm{\,th}\ $ column of the $\ 49\times49\ $ identity matrix, so
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\,\mathbf{h}_{25}+p\,\mathbf{h}_{32}\right)^{T}\left(\mathbf{H}^{T}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{H}^{-1}\left(\,\mathbf{h}_{25}+p\,\mathbf{h}_{32}\right)&=&\left( \mathbf{i}_{25}+p\,\mathbf{i}_{32}\right)^T\left( \mathbf{i}_{25}+p\,\mathbf{i}_{32}\right)\\
&=& 1 + p^2\ ,
\end{eqnarray}
and the condition required for the inverse to exist is not satisfied.

**Direct demonstration that $\ M\ $ is singular**

First note that the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{H}^{T}&\mathbf{i}_{25}^{}+p\,\mathbf{i}_{32}^{}\\\mathbf{h}_{25}^{T}+p\,\mathbf{h}_{32}^{T}&1+p^2\end{bmatrix}
$$
is singular because its $50^\mathrm{th}$ row is the sum of its $25^\mathrm{th}$ row and $\ p\ $ times its $32^\mathrm{nd}$ row. Thus,
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{M}&=&\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{H}^{}\mathbf{H}^{T}&\mathbf{h}_{25}^{}+p\,\mathbf{h}_{32}^{}\\\mathbf{h}_{25}^{T}+p\,\mathbf{h}_{32}^{T}&1+p^2\end{bmatrix}\\
&=&\
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{H} &\mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf{0}^T & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{H}^{T}&\mathbf{i}_{25}^{}+p\,\mathbf{i}_{32}^{}\\\mathbf{h}_{25}^{T}+p\,\mathbf{h}_{32}^{T}&1+p^2\end{bmatrix}\ ,
\end{eqnarray}
as a product of one matrix with another *singular* matrix, is also singular.

Comment: I am trying to understand your answer. I the mean while I found a mistake and fixed it (highlighted in red). Secondly when testing in MATLAB, inverse does exists. So matrix is not singular.

Comment: @NAASI. Unfortunately your suggested edit to my answer was rejected, so I didn't see it until after I had found the error and corrected it myself.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your notation, you can show that your matrix $\ \mathbf{M}\ $ is singular by a more direct method I will now add to my answer.  I will also change the notation I use for the columns of the identity matrix, which might have been confusing.